# Override debug template in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Guys see if you can help me I want to customize the page that symfony renders by default, I located the template and I specifically want to overrideException_full.html.php.

Regarding this, symfont does not provide documentation.

From already thank you very much!

I have a controller and I show you the code, the problem is that I think the solution for this php template is not here:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @author Lucas Espantoso <espantoso.lucas@hotmail.com>
 */

namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorRenderer\HtmlErrorRenderer;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\FlattenException;

class ErrorController extends AbstractController
{


    public function isDebug(): bool
    {
        return $this->getParameter('kernel.debug');
    }

    protected function renderOverride(\Throwable $exception, string $siteName): FlattenException
    {

        //  HtmlErrorRenderer::setTemplate('views/override_error.html.php');


        $errorRenderer = new HtmlErrorRenderer($this->isDebug());
        $overrideException = $errorRenderer->render($exception);

        $solutionHTML = '<svg width="24" height="24" style="fill:white"><use xlink:href="./assets/img/sprites/logo.svg#white_logo"></use></svg>&nbsp<b>'.$siteName.'</b>&nbsp-&nbsp';
        $originalHTML = $overrideException->getAsString();

        $firstTraceNode = '<h1 class="logo">';

        $modifiedHTML = str_replace(
            $firstTraceNode,
            $firstTraceNode.$solutionHTML,
            $originalHTML
        );

        return $overrideException->setAsString($modifiedHTML);
    }

    protected function defaultErrorRender(\Throwable $exception): Response
    {
        $exception =  FlattenException::createWithDataRepresentation($exception);
        $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
        $response =  $this->render('/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig', ['ex' => $statusCode]);
        $response->setStatusCode($statusCode);
        return $response;
    }

    public function show(\Throwable $exception, $logger, Request $request, string $siteName): Response
    {


        if (!$this->isDebug()) {
            return $this->defaultErrorRender($exception);
        } else {

            if (strpos($request->getPathInfo(), 'error/')) {
                return $this->defaultErrorRender($exception);
            }

            $throwable  = $this->renderOverride($exception, $siteName);
            return new Response($throwable->getAsString(), $throwable->getStatusCode(), $throwable->getHeaders());
        }
    }
}
```